# Data sources to get past news articles

Tags: programming, data-source

Are there data sources from which we could get news articles from the last 2 years? I tried reuters but they had data spanning back to just 3 months.

Any suggestion/pointers are appreciated

Answer (score 3):

AYLIEN provides historical news content via an API. You can try it [here](https://newsapi.aylien.com/demo#!/?published_at.start=NOW-30DAYS%2FDAY&published_at.end=NOW&sort_by=recency).

Full disclosure I work for AYLIEN.

Answer (score 2):

At [CloudQuant](http://info.cloudquant.com) we have been using historical sentiment data and news data from bloomberg. This news includes the news title text. I believe that the full text is also available but we aren't using it. We allow our clients in the CloudQuant Elite product to be able to access the news sentiment in our historical backtesting.

Bloomberg's "EVENT-DRIVEN TRADING TEXTUAL NEWS" and real time data can be found at: https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/product/event-driven-feeds/

Comment: We now have this formalized with a much better API and sample code. 


For the News from bloomberg your backtesting script can access the titles.


There is also historical information for Alexandria and StockTwits.



[See CloudQuant User Forums](https://forum.cloudquant.com/discussion/198/sentiment-data-from-alexandria-bloomberg-stocktwits?utm_medium=QuantitativeFinance)

Answer (score 0):

Webhose.io API provides historical data going back to Jan 2008. Here is the [link](https://docs.webhose.io/docs/archive-historical-data).